# why is insertRowsAfter() not working in my spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a script that insert a row after the row where cursor is currently located.
For example if my cursor is on "A3" in the spreadsheet, I want to insert a row at 4th row from the script.
I run the following script.

```
function insertChild(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var active=sheet.getActiveCell();
sheet.insertRowsAfter(active.getRow(), 1)
}
```

But this code inserts a row at the second row, instead of fourth row. It seems that `getActiveCell()` points at "A1" instead of "A3".

Is there any way to insert a row based on the current cursor location?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, there's typos. My cursor is on "A3" now. And want to insert a row at "4:4" area.

Comment: I edit my original post related to A1 notations.

Comment: Are you sure the cursor points on A3 I'll do a test an come back

Comment: it works form me, your code is ok make sure your cursor points on the correct cell

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdYFgeSt1oUzYafpRGi5sKlZhx2fXxgCsDrpQt843cA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I shared the spreadsheet. I freeze the 1st&2nd rows. I make sure that I set my cursor on A3 but always new row is inserted at 2nd row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally fine and works.
By the way you could use `insertRowAfter(row)` if you just want to add one row.

```
function insertChild(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(cell.getRow());
}
```